# How pass object's array in parameter to component in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript and I have this trivial error.

(property) data: menuItems[]
Type '{ data: menuItems[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & menuItems[]'.
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & menuItems[]'.ts(2322)

Here is code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/data-is-not-a-function-ju21g6?file=/src/Settings.tsx

And here is another combined with the first one
https://codesandbox.io/s/data-is-not-a-function-ju21g6?file=/src/TreeSettings.tsx:256-320

```
interface IMenuItems {
  name: string;
  level: number;
  id: number;
  pid: number;
  children?: any[];
}

const Settings = () => {
  const { flattenarr, zerotreetoarr } = useConvertTree();
  const [data, setData] = useState<menuItems[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    zerotreetoarr(tree.children as [], [0]);
    setData(flattenarr);
  }, []);
  return <TreeSettings data={data} />;
};
```

```
export interface IMenuItems {
  name: string;
  level: number;
  id: number;
  pid: number;
  children?: any[];
}
const TreeSettings = (data: menuItems[]) => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((t) => {
        return <div>{t.name}</div>;
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

```
The problem in Settings.tsx at <TreeSettings data={data} />; on data I get

(property) data: menuItems[]
Type '{ data: menuItems[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & menuItems[]'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & menuItems[]'.ts(2322)
```

How do I pass the data in the prop with types ?

Answer (score 0):

U cant use interface as type parameter, but u can use typeof IMenuItems like this:

```
 const TreeSettings = (data:typeof 
 menuItems[]) => {
 return (
  <>
   {data.map((t) => {
     return <div>{t.name}</div>;
   })}
  </>
  );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Function components are defined like so in Typescript:

```js
import type { FC } from "react";

...

const TreeSettings: FC<{data: menuItems[]}> = ({data}) => {
  ...
}
```

`FC` stands for Function Component. It is a generic type that allows you to define the type of `props`, in this case `{data: menuItems[]}`. You can then destructure the props, in this case: `({data})`, and the correct type will be inferred.

Fixed sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/data-is-not-a-function-forked-spp0xn?file=/src/TreeSettings.tsx

---

In your case you were not destructuring the `props` object. Instead you declared the entire props object to have type `menuItems[]` which is incorrect.

This line:

```
<TreeSettings data={data} />;
```

is equivalent to

```
TreeSettings({data: data})
```

This passes an object with a `data` property to the Function Component.

It does not pass the array as the parameter.